# How to make the entire project's navigation bar black in Swift and iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, statusbar

I want to set the status bar as black for the entire project. I have Pagination, Modal views, Navigation stacks in my project. Is there a way to set the status bar a black for complete project. I've seen this in Android apps. I have tried to set status bar as Light in AppDelegate, have set View-Controllers based navigation bar to NO/YES in plist. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling this form `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` should work.

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView else {
    return
}

statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Comment: Thank you Harsh. Will try and let you know if this works. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Hi Harsh, I am able to change the status bar color now to black. But now I am not able to see the battery and wifi signals etc.(as those are also in black). I have to make them white. So, I need to change the status bar to Light for the entire project. I tried to do this in App Delegate but its not working. Can you please help ?

Comment: You need to set the status bar as light colored in the plist.